# Framework/Suggestions for Small, simple web apps

Tags: frameworks

I am looking create small simple applications that are fun social toys. They won't be complicated, usually a one-type CRUD type deal. For example,

1. Generate a random sentence (from source/algorithm)
2. Store this in a database
3. Present this sentence to the user
4. Present a text box to allow them to enter their own sentence.
5. record sentence in the database with a relation to first sentance

then another part of this site would

1. grab entries from database
2. present them in interesting ways via relationships.

Ok so that's just an example, but most of these fit this bill. Now I'm a drupal developer and I could do them in drupal but:

- It ties them to my site or one main drupal base (They are conceptually and visually independent)
- One drupal installation per site is not realistic.
- I'd like to use something other than PHP, preferably a functional language.

So I'd be interested in hearing about frameworks that are good for

- rapid prototyping of small, flexible and fast CRUD.
- preferably a functional language or some other language with **interesting and new** features (for a php dev).
- provide enough structure to not reinvent the wheel, but enough control to reinvent if i need to.

Thanks!
 - not PHP

Answer (score 2):

I've been using AppJet (http://appjet.com) for this lately. It's client-server, where both the client and the server are scripted with simple Javascript. The system is extremely simple but powerful enough to create some simple toys. It also supports a small space of persistent storage that is table-based (i.e. not MySQL, but straightforward enough).

The only downsides to using it are (a) you're very much restricted to Javascript and what you can do in it and (b) your source code (client and server) can be viewed by other people.

If you want to try getting into Python, Google App Engine (http://code.google.com/appengine/) is also convenient. It's more complicated, but you don't have to show people your source code.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very generic answer but maybe you could try any of the following and which suits your taste:

- Ruby + Rails
- Python + Django
- Erlang based web framework called
  Erlyweb
- web.py a simple python based
  framework.

If you are inclined towards using a functional language, it does not get better than Erlang but a WARNING-- it may take you time getting used to syntax. I think ROR and Django framework should be your top 2. I would go for Django and if you find Ruby "cute" you might look at ROR.

Answer (score 1):

Rails.

If you want functional you could play with Erlyweb...

Answer (score 1):

Django/Python should be worth a look. Coming from php I found much it more interesting and productive to work with and it has a lot of really nice features.